# C# RequireHttpsAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, https, attributes

I'm trying to create my own RequireHttps attribute because I don't want to use the RequireHttpsAttribute from Mvc. I just want to reject non secure connections instead of forcing them to resend them using SSL. I copied a function from Microsoft web page, but for some reason, the attribute rejects both connections, http and https.

This is my code, anyone has any idea of how to fix it or another way to approach the solution?

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true,
    AllowMultiple = true)]
public class RequireHttpsAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                ReasonPhrase = "HTTPS Required"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
actionContext.Request.Method != HttpMethod.Options
```

This part of the conditional will reject any request that does not use the `OPTIONS` HTTP method.  So what this conditional translates to is that it will reject any requests except `OPTIONS` requests made over HTTPS.  This would include any `GET`, `POST`, etc.

Try leaving off the second part of the conditional:

```
if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
```

Comment: I tried it without that code, but still not working properly.

Comment: @Brujah Have you tried running in a debugger and stepping through the code to figure out why HTTPS requests would be rejected?

Comment: I tried, but I had some problems sending https to my localhost using web debuggers. While trying with normal http, everything seems to be normal: actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme = "http" and Uri.UriSchemeHttps = "https", so I understand that https should be accepted. But that's not the case, and I wonder if I'm missing something.

Comment: I don't mean a web debugger, I mean run the MVC application in debug mode in Visual Studio and set a breakpoint in your `OnAuthorization` method, then send in an HTTPS request and step through to see why it's being rejected.

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm debugging the web application. I send the packages using the web debugger(Fiddler), and analyze the behavior debugging with VS. But sending https request to my localhost instance from VS seems to be harder that expected (doesn't reach the system, while http does). Still, I'm trying other debuggers right now.

Comment: @Brujah If it doesn't reach the system, this implies that the issue is not in your source code but in your server configuration.  Perhaps it is not listening on the HTTPS port?

Comment: But deployed into my web host, the packages reach the system, and got rejected. I didn't wanted to mess with the https port into my localhost if not necessary, but seems like it is.